# Helping Mandy become a better speller

Tags: string-manipulation, curated-data, code-review, chemistry

tl;dr *Can you improve upon this code, which checks to see if a word can be spelled using the element symbols from the periodic table?*

---

I recently created a [periodic table that lights up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eI-IgJ3n_RU).  The design relies heavily on a Raspberry Pi running *Mathematica* to display curated data in what I hope is a visually pleasing fashion.  I mention over at the [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1098055) forum how *Mathematica* has played a role in multiple aspects of the project design and implementation.

Spelling words with elements is [something people apparently enjoy](https://www.google.com/search?q=spelling+words+with+periodic+table&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X), so now I am trying to make Mandy spell, along the lines of the Christmas lights in [Stranger Things](http://hellogiggles.com/everyone-obsessed-stranger-things-can-now-make-christmas-lights-message/).  (If you are a fan of the show, don't get your hopes up, as the GIF generator doesn't work anymore.)

It turns out, writing code to find words that can be spelled using element symbols is not too complicated (but note, I am using v9, so `ElementData` is returning strings rather than Entities):

```
(* Wolfram - please bring ElementData up to date *)
sym = (ElementData[#, "Symbol"] & /@ Range[118]) /. {"Uut" -> "Nh", 
    "Uup" -> "Mc", "Uus" -> "Ts", "Uuo" -> "Og"} // ToLowerCase;
(* Check if the first 1(2) characters of string can be represented by an 
   element symbol *)
beginwithelement[s_String] := 
 MemberQ[sym, If[StringLength[s] >= #, StringTake[s, #]]] & /@ {2, 1}
(* Remove characters from a string if they represent a valid element *)
elemcheck[w_] := With[{c = beginwithelement[ToLowerCase@w]},
  If[Or @@ c,
   If[First@c == True, StringDrop[w, 2], StringDrop[w, 1]],
   False]]
(* Keep removing valid element symbols from string if possible, 
   returning list of elements or False *)
spell[w_String] := 
 With[{lst = 
    NestWhileList[elemcheck, w, If[StringQ[#], StringLength@# > 0] &]},
  If[Last@lst === "",
   Reverse@
    Table[StringDrop[lst[[-(i + 1)]], -StringLength[lst[[-i]]]], {i, 
      1, Length@lst - 1}], False]]
```

With these functions, it is relatively straightforward to first look for all words that start with an element and then use `spell` to test whether or not the word can be spelled entirely with element symbols.

```
words = DictionaryLookup[# ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True] & /@ Sort@sym;
icanspell = DeleteCases[spell /@ #, False] & /@ words;
```

This routine finds over 17000 words that can be spelled using elemental symbols.  The longest words appear to be 18 characters long: **conversationalists** and **hypersensitivities**.

**Herein lies the problem**  The longest (English) word that can be spelled with element symbols is [nonrepresentationalisms](https://sciencenotes.org/longest-word-using-periodic-table-symbols/).  Now, *Mathematica* doesn't know this word, `DictionaryLookup["nonrepresentationalisms"] == {} (* True *)`, but even if I try to spell it with my function, it fails: `spell["nonrepresentationalisms"] (* False *)`.  The *problem*, I believe, is that `elemcheck` is biased towards two-character symbols rather than one-character symbols.  Changing this bias does change the overall number of words found (to ~ 13000) but does not allow for "*No N Re P Re Se N Ta Ti O N Al I Sm S*" to be found because sometimes 1-letter symbols should be preferred (P instead of Pr for the 6th character) and sometimes the two-letter character is needed (Se instead of S for the 9th character).

**The question** is this: How might I modify the above code to traverse multiple pathways when needed?  Alternatively, is there a different approach to creating a function that determines if a string of alphabetical characters can be represented by element symbols?

Comment: I agree, thanks @IstvánZachar.  I missed that thread.

Comment: I was hesitant about the exact dupe, as your question also provides some nice background for the task at hand. Plus it has lighting periodic tables, wohooo! :)